# How to render template values using javascript - Meteor

Tags: javascript, templates, dynamic, meteor, render

how to render the contents of a template .. i can;t pass through this point :/ thanks for your help

example :

```
<body>
  {{> dash}}
</body>

<template name="dash">
<div id="example2" class='example_block'> 
    <form name = "frm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Template Name
                <td>:
                <td><input type="text" name = tname class = "tname">
      </frm>
       <div class='demo'>
            <input type='button' value='Click Here to Create Window' class="btn"/> 
        </div> 
    </div>
<div id = "window_block8" style="display:none;"></div>
</template>

<template name="t1">
    try1
</template>

<template  name="t2">
    try2 
</template>

   //client.js
 Template.dash.events({
'click input.btn' : function(){
    var temp = document.frm.tname.value ;
    Session.set("template" , temp);
            $('body').append(Meteor.render(Template[Session.get("currentTemplate")]()));
     }
 });
```

some thing like this.. but that code wont work on me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Meteor.render(Template.try)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render) returns a document fragment which you can insert into your page with jQuery or vanilla JS.

e.g

```
Template.dash.aw = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(Meteor.render(Template.try));
}
```

Note that you can use array-style notation if the template name is variable:

```
document.body.appendChild(Meteor.render(Template[Session.get("currentTemplate")]));
```

Alternatively, if you only want to return a variable and not an entire template:

```
Template.try.var = function() {
    return 'Hello';
}
Template.dash.aw = function() {
    return Template.try.var();
}
// Template.dash.aw = Template.try.var = function() {
//    return 'Hello';
// }
```

The commented function is probably inadequate, since you want some logic in `Template.dash.aw`

Comment: thanks bro .. :)  .. but what i want is to get the data inside the template name = try ...

Comment: Sorry, the code didn't format properly - see the first two examples

Comment: Are there any errors in the console log? Could you post a js fiddle?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. Note the lack of parentheses after `Template.try` now - `Meteor.render` takes a __function__, not a __html string__

Comment: No worries. If the answer is fine, you can accept it by clicking the greyed out tick to the left of the answer

Comment: ahmm .. what is this [object DocumentFragment] thingy ? after i use render , it returns a document fragment (id , landmark , etc.. )

Comment: ohh.. its okay now :) but there's a problem,  the input buttons inside  t1 won't work in 
Template.t1.events

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. Please update the answer for Meteor versions after Blaze was introduced.